# Can I call setcookie in a included script when the include occurs after output?

Tags: php, cookies

I know that setcookie() has to be called before any output is put on the page, but I don't know what would happen when includes are involved. Let's say I have two files named A.php and B.php that look like this:

A.php:

```
<?php
setcookie("key", "value", time() + (60*60*24));
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

B.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include("A.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

If I open B.php in my web browser, does setcookie get called after the html and body open tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `setcookie` will **not** work if you include `A.php` in `B.php`.

A common way to avoid outputting anything is to start an output buffer. At the top of `B.php` put:

```
<?php ob_start();?>
```

Then at the end put:

```
<?php echo ob_get_clean(); // flush the buffer ?>
```